# Babel loader failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following example class, containing an example class property arrow function:

```
class ExampleClass {
    example = (params) => {
        return params
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this construction isn't yet being well recognized:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/example/example.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (284:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|     example = (params) => {
|         return params
|     }
 @ ./src/example/index.js 8:17-48
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./src
```

I have been using the following babel presets and webpack configurations:

**Webpack Config**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

I have no idea what else I need to import here, I'll admit I'm not exactly sure how I would find that out through googling.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can declare method in class with this syntax.

```
class ExampleClass {
    example(params) {
        return params
    }
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out. I used an example class to shorten the question but the code was coming from a third party source installed in node_modules. The webpack config excludes node_modules for performance reasons. I'll have to talk to the author for him to use the transpiler on his script before publishing.

Comment: I have just figured out that "stage-2" is sufficient to compile this syntax

class ExampleClass {
    example = (params) => {
        return params
    }
}

ref:
https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTAwuK0DeAUNMdOoqhtALzQAUKYATshAJTUB8-RJvj6AFwCujAHbQGzJBB7EAvgTlA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=stage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=